# Office-JS: Excel Host API no longer available under Excel 2016 MSO

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm currently running Windows 10 with Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.04266.1001) 64-bit. I'm under the impression that that is the version installed via MSI.

Over the course of the last few months I've implemented a React-based Excel add-in using the Excel Host APIs. Per the [Excel JavaScript API requirement sets](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) document available at the Office Dev Center, that build appears to contain the "ExcelApi 1.1, WordApi 1.1, and common API" requirement sets.

As of yesterday, I am no longer able to access the Excel host APIs through JavaScript or through the F12 developer tools (`window.Excel === undefined`). It appears that all the functionality under that had previously existed under that namespace has become unavailable.

It appears that (among other scripts), the office.js script loaded from the CDN now requests and embeds [Excel-15.02.js](http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Excel-15.02.js) for the add-in.

I do not know the version of `Excel-*.js` that was being embedded before yesterday, but after perusing the contents of both `Excel-15.02.js`, `Excel-winrt-16.00.js` and other versions available on the CDN, I *suspect* that it was a later version than 15.02.

For the record, both of the following runtime checks return `false` - I say both, because "API" is capitalized inconsistently in the documentation available at [dev.office.com](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).

```
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelApi", 1.1); // false
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("ExcelAPI", 1.1); // false
```

Please advise; best regards.

Comment: This is very surprising, and is most certainly a bug if this is the case.  Let me investigate.

Is there anything that happened yesterday that you think could have caused this (any update, etc.?)

Comment: Thank you so much — yesterday I rebooted the machine and re-inserted the add-in. If I recall, before I rebooted I briefly had two Excel instances, one with an already-loaded, long-running add-in that worked as expected and a newly-inserted one that didn't. Otherwise, it looks like the only recent Windows update was a pair of updates downloaded and installed on the 25th of February.

For what it's worth, it works as expected in Excel for Mac v15.31 - though I don't know that that rules out some kind of error on my end.

Answer (score 2):

I am investigating the issue.  A few questions:

1. You mention that the files being loaded include Excel-15*.js files.  How are you seeing this -- is it through Fiddler, or through a debugger?  If you can send a Fiddler trace, that would be really useful (a Fiddler trace may contain some sensitive info, so you may want to scrub it -- and feel free to send it to me directly rather than posting it here online)
2. If you browse to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js in a browser, what is the version number that you see at the top of the file?
3. If you are comfortable deleting your IE cache: could you see if the issue continues to repro even after you've cleared the cache?

Feel free to reply here via comments, or as updates to your questions, or to email me directly.  My email is my full name (separated by a dot between first and last) at microsoft.com.

I will be updating this answer as I have more info.

Comment: I have set up a repro machine with the RTM MSI install of Office 2016 -- but am not seeing the issue.  If you could provide more info (see questions above), that would be most helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: 1. I'm currently doing all my debugging through the F12 Developer Tools in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12.
2. v16.0.7819.1000 loads in both the browser (IE/Edge) and Excel.
3. I went ahead and cleared cache in IE, the issue persists.

I was able to run the add-in on another machine in the latest version of Excel. The initially-installed Excel 2016 presented with the same issue (don't have access to a version/build number; it was slightly newer than the version that prompted this question). After updating to the latest available version (v.1701 / build 7766.260), it now works as expected.

Comment: @NoahLange, thanks for the details.  To make sure I understand correctly:  it sounds like you switched from an Office 2016 MSI install to an Office 365 subscription (as that is what build 7766 looks like to me).  Is that so?  In that case, the original issue still remains, so I want to make sure that we don't close this prematurely.

Comment: Exactly. The issue — as far as I can tell — still exists, but we've sidestepped it by updating Excel. We still have the MSI install around, so if there's any more info you need we can provide it.

Comment: Hello Michael! Any news about this? One of my customers is having the same issue. (16.0.4266.1001)
On my machine I have also installed Office 2016 via MSI installer, but the issue is not occuring and my version is a little higher (16.0.4639.1000). 
How can my customer update to this version too? Is he missing some Windows Updates?

Comment: @ndreisg, what is the exact API that you're having issues with?  Are you sure that it's marked as belonging to ExcelApi 1.1?

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind:  could you open an issue for it on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, so that we can discuss it and track it there?  Otherwise I'm afraid it might get lost here, deep down in the comments to a year-old thread...

Comment: I'm having this issue with Range.getResizedRange which should be available since ExcelApi 1.1 according to documentation.

Comment: Issue on github created: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/136