# Fail to load addin on Excel 2016 2016 16.0.4266.1001

Tags: office-js

our excel addin failed to load on Windows Excel 2016 16.0.4266.1001, based on the requirement, 2016 16.0.4266.1001 is the version installed through MSI, can you help us?

[Excel version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJXW.jpg)
[Addin loading errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xrMP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of
[Office-JS: Excel Host API no longer available under Excel 2016 MSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563791/office-js-excel-host-api-no-longer-available-under-excel-2016-mso)

Let me check again to see if we can diagnose the issue.

Comment: Also, if you can provide the same debugging info as I requested in the other question, that would be great!